# Get specific column from query based on reference type

Tags: sql-server-2012

I m getting two column from join query. My requirement is : I need to add one flag column called ReferenceType. if i pass RefType='A' then it should return first column value, If i pass RefType='X' then is should return second column value.

**Query:**

```
select A.AID, X.XID
from ABC A left outer join XYZ X
on A.AID = X.AID

╔═══════╦═══════╗
║ A.AID ║ X.XID ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║   1   ║  11   ║
║   2   ║  12   ║
║   3   ║  13   ║
║   4   ║  14   ║
║   5   ║  15   ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝
```

For following query it should return A.AID column
Query:

```
select A.AID, X.XID
from ABC A left outer join XYZ X
    on A.AID = X.AID
where ReferenceType='A'
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS SQL 2012: use `[IIF()][1]`:

```
SELECT IIF(ReferenceType='A', A.AID, X.XID )
from ABC A left outer join XYZ X
    on A.AID = X.AID
```